# Finding and removing duplicate column values in a SQL Server row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

Yes, another SQL duplicates question :)

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 table with multiple `phone number` columns, looking something like:

```
ID   Tel1   Tel2   Tel3   Tel4   Tel5   Tel6
 1    123    456    789   NULL   NULL   NULL
 2    123    456    123    123   NULL   NULL
 3    456    789    123    456   NULL   NULL
```

I'd like to remove the duplicate phone numbers from each row - for example, in row ID 2, I need to NULL Tel3 and Tel4, and in row 3 I need to NULL Tel4. I don't need to check for duplicates between rows - the same phone number can exist between in multiple rows, just not in different columns in the same row.

Can anyone suggest the best way to get rid of these duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d247/3).

```
update PhoneNumbers
   set Tel2 = case when Tel1 = Tel2 
                   then null 
                   else Tel2 end,
       Tel3 = case when Tel3 in (Tel1, Tel2) 
                   then null 
                   else Tel3 end,
       Tel4 = case when Tel4 in (Tel1, Tel2, Tel3) 
                   then null 
                   else Tel4 end,
       Tel5 = case when Tel5 in (Tel1, Tel2, Tel3, Tel4) 
                   then null 
                   else Tel5 end,
       Tel6 = case when Tel6 in (Tel1, Tel2, Tel3, Tel4, Tel5) 
                   then null 
                   else Tel6 end
```

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović +1 didn't though to do it all in one step, nice one! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find them using `UNPIVOT`...

```
select id, telNo 
from phonenumbertable
unpivot 
( telNo for tel in (tel1, tel2, tel3, tel4,tel5, tel6)) as u    
group by id,telno
having COUNT(telno)>1
```

Comment: OK, that'd help me find duplicates, but what about NULL'ing them out?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to update it like this:

```
update tablename
set Tel6 = null
where Tel6 = Tel5 or Tel6 = Tel4 or Tel6 = Tel3 or Tel6 = Tel3 or Tel6 = Tel2 or Tel6 = Tel1
```

and then do the same update (with fewer comparisons in the where clause) to the other columns (except the first one).