# How do I remove repeated column values from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

select * from TableName

FROM THIS:

```
ID     Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4    Col5
1       aa      21      ss     m        p
2       aa      21      tt     f        u
3       bb      21      ss     f        d
4       bb      22      ss     m        d
```

TO THIS

```
ID     Col1    Col2    Col3   Col4    Col5
1       aa      21      ss     m        p
2                       tt     f        u
3       bb              ss              d
4               22             m
```

i want this Output is it possible ?

don't want repeat duplicate value if it next to the same

Thanks for your time.

Comment: refer this, this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189218/how-do-i-remove-repeated-column-values-from-report

Comment: here i used Break on Stud_name
select ID,Stud_Name,Stud_Age,Stud_Addr,Stud_Gender,Stud_Qualification from student 
order by ID
but error is Msg 135, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Cannot use a BREAK statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737765/finding-and-removing-duplicate-column-values-in-a-sql-server-row

Comment: how to use break on for this condition...

Comment: hello SRIRAM may you tell me how to use this BRAKE ON

Comment: What the heck is "marmalization"? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select everything you want to temporary table, clear repeated values and return result set from updated temporary table.

Query might look like this:

```
select 1 as id, 'aa' as col1, '21' as col2,'ss' as col3,'m' as col4,'p' as col5 into #tmp union
select 2, 'aa','21','tt','f','u' union
select 3, 'bb','21','ss','f','d' union
select 4, 'bb','22','ss','m','d' 


update t set
    col1 = case when tp.col1 = t.col1 then '' else t.col1 end,
    col2 = case when tp.col2 = t.col2 then '' else t.col2 end,
    col3 = case when tp.col3 = t.col3 then '' else t.col3 end,
    col4 = case when tp.col4 = t.col4 then '' else t.col4 end,
    col5 = case when tp.col5 = t.col5 then '' else t.col5 end
from #tmp t
left join (
    select t1.id, max(t2.id) as pid
    from #tmp t1
    join #tmp t2 on t1.id > t2.id
    group by t1.id
) p on t.id = p.id
left join #tmp tp on p.pid = tp.id
```

Result:

```
/*------------------------
select top 100 * from  #tmp
------------------------*/
id   col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1    aa      21      ss      m       p
2                    tt      f       u
3    bb              ss              d
4            22              m
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4991/1)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the query, is this what you need?:

```
update a set 
    a.Col1=(case when cnt1=1 then a.Col1 else null end),
    a.Col2=(case when cnt2=1 then a.Col2 else null end),
    a.Col3=(case when cnt3=1 then a.Col3 else null end)
from TableName a
join
(
    select *, 
        row_number() over (Partition By Col1 order by ID) cnt1,
        row_number() over (Partition By Col2 order by ID) cnt2,
        row_number() over (Partition By Col3 order by ID) cnt3
    From TableName
) x on a.ID=x.ID
```

Comment: hello bro its updating every entry i want only col wise if next element is same as previous so please review this once again